# Add tag to xml filed in oracle (transform xml)

Tags: xml, oracle, transform, xmltype

I have table with filed "XmlInfo". This field is a varchar2 and contain XML.
Don't ask why it is varchar2 - this is old database structure.

I need to "add" one tag in this xml.
So I used xmltype.createXML and APPENDCHILDXML combination. Problem is with output.

Original field is without indent. So first I use xmlserialize with "no indent" option. Unfortunately this is available only in oracle 11, and I need to this query work on both 10 and 11 oracle.

So I use transform. But again I'm stuck.

**Original value:**

```
<info><Managed>False</Managed></info>
```

**Expected:**

```
<info><Managed>False</Managed><ChangedDate>2013-09-11</ChangedDate></info>
```

I use this query

```
select xmltype.createXML(t1.XmlInfo).APPENDCHILDXML('//info',XMLTYPE.CREATEXML('<ChangedDate>'|| to_char(sysdate, 'yyyy-mm-dd') ||'</ChangedDate>'))
  .transform(xmltype(
    '<?xml version="1.0"?><xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"><xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="no"/><xsl:template match="@*|node()"><xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/></xsl:copy></xsl:template></xsl:stylesheet>'
  )).getStringVal()
from table1 t1
```

**Result in Oracle 11 (as expected):**

```
<info><Managed>False</Managed><ChangedDate>2013-09-11</ChangedDate></info>
```

**Result in Oracle 10 (there is new line char):**

```
<info>
<Managed>False</Managed>
<ChangedDate>2013-09-11</ChangedDate>
</info>
```

What is wrong with this transform, or is there any way to write this query and work as expected in both version of oracle?

Remarks:
In next step I'll have to update this value, so I'll use "updatexml". This is why I cannot just concatenate two string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve the problem by removing completely xml engine and play with plain text...

By combining `substr`, `instr` and `case` statement I create ugly, obscure SQL that inject correct date in specific place.
Depending on existence of *ChangedDate* string and old value in this node.


This is workaround so I marked question as answered. But if some one knows the real answer for indentation problem, let me know. Because next update could be not so *easy* to handle with just string functions...

Answer (score 0):

What problems give you indentation? Anyway, you just put it back into a VARCHAR2, so you could just strip out indentation with a simple REGEX_REPLACE matching the [:space:] class between your tags; something like:

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(indentedxml, ">[[:space:]]+<", "><")
```

Comment: For me - indentation is irrelevant, but 3rd software we use get lost when where is something between brackets :/  Second: your example remove spaces as tag value (eg. `<tag>   </tag>`).

Answer (score 0):

It's not easy to use, but [XMLTransform](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10500_01/appdev.920/a96620/xdb07tra.htm#1026231) is the right operator if you need to generate a specific representation of your XML.